# Running bash script on server

Tags: php, bash, html

I want to create a webpage control page to my remote server.

I want to be able to run my own local scripts by pressing buttons on the webpage.

I have followed some advice from (stackoverflow) and created this:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['button'])) { exec('//xxx.yy.zz.v/Users/me/webtest.sh'); } ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="button">MY TEXT</button>
</form>
```

webtest.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x

echo "WOW ME" > /cygdrive/d/jobs/web.test
```

It does not appear that webtest.sh runs when I press the button.

Comment: Why don't you just use CRON jobs

Comment: Can I link it to a button?

Comment: Well you could use curl to send a POST, which would be the effect of pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

First check this line `exec('//xxx.yy.zz.v/Users/me/webtest.sh');` to execute a sh file from php you need to use ./path/file.sh or sh path/file.sh

can be `exec('./path/file.sh')`, then set appropriate file permission to webtest.sh and web.test so that webserver can access those file. 
You can check the error logs in

`tail -f /var/log/apache or http/errorlogs`

Comment: How can I tell if PHP is getting called at all? I don't get any errors or feedback. The "tail" you suggest cannot find those files

Comment: which platform you running this bash script? 
Default log location
`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log` 
`tail -f /var/log/apache2/access_log`